# EnitityManager remove - IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: java.lang.Integer] with root cause

Tags: java, mysql, spring, transactions, entitymanager

I did this example while learning spring and everything worked, now I'm writing my own project and I don't understand why I'm getting ERROR: Unknown entity: java.lang.Integer when I try to perform a remove operation from the EntityManager class to remove an object from the MySQL database

Product class (i don't paste here all methods like getters and setters etc.)

```java
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    @OneToOne
    private ProductType type;

    private float price;

    private String description;

    //more code...
}
```

ProductRepository (i show only delete method)

```java
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

public class DBProductRepository implements ProductRepository{
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void deleteProduct(Integer id) {
        entityManager.remove(id);
    }

    //more code...
}
```

ProductService (i show only delete method)

```java
@Service
public class ProductService {
    public void deleteProduct(Integer id) {
        productRepository.deleteProduct(id);
    }
    //more code...
}
```

ProductController

```java
@Controller
public class ProductController {
    @RequestMapping("/products")
    public String getProducts(Model model){
        List<Product> products = productService.getAllProducts();
        model.addAttribute("products",products);
        return "products";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/product/delete/{id}")
    public String deleteProduct(@PathVariable("id") Integer id){
        productService.deleteProduct(id);
        return "redirect:/products";
    }
    //more code...
}
```

products.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Product list</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css}"/>

    <script th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>Type</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>Description</td>

        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr th:each=" product : ${products}">
            <td th:text="${product.id}"></td>
            <td th:text="${product.type}"></td>
            <td th:text="${product.name}"></td>
            <td th:text="${product.price}"></td>
            <td th:text="${product.description}"></td>
            <td><a th:href="${'/product/delete/'+product.id}">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When i click delete on site localhost:8080/products i got:
"Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Mon Sep 16 17:41:45 CEST 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Unknown entity: java.lang.Integer"

In console:
"2019-09-16 17:41:45.175 ERROR 7792 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: java.lang.Integer] with root cause"

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`EntityManager#remove`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#remove-java.lang.Object-) takes an *entity instance* as parameter. You are passing `Integer`.

Change to:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void deleteProduct(Product product) {
    entityManager.remove(product);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works! I don't understand why example in course working on Integer not Object.

In the controller I pass the object to delete this way (it works), but could I find out if this is the correct method? Can it be solved better?

    @RequestMapping(value="/product/delete/{id}")
    public String deleteProduct(@PathVariable("id") Integer id){
        productService.deleteProduct(productService.getProduct(id));
        return "redirect:/products";

Comment: @misza Use `POST` method to do it. Other than that I don't think there is any issue.